# Git / Terminal: How to remove file from inside folder?

Tags: terminal, git, svn

I have a .svn folder from another project which committed by accident when I committed the whole project folder.

How would you remove the .svn folder from a path like projects/projectname/js/.svn ?

I tried rm and -1 got error messages

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-r` is an argument to `git rm`. You should run the command `git rm -r portfolio/shabang/js/.svn`. You can run `git help rm` to get more help about the different arguments to `git rm`.